# Refer existing resource group instead of creating a new one on each packer build

Tags: azure, packer

There is a peculiar issue while build image using packer. Our service principle in azure will not have access to create or delete resource group, whereas packer is trying to create the temporary resource group in each build.

I changed the **temp_resource_group_name** to **build_resource_group_name** which is pointing to an existing resource group. Post that I got following error message while building, can you please help me figure our where I'm doing wrong.

> Specify either a location to create the resource group in or an
>   existing build resource group name, but not both packer stack overflow

Comment: Hi, do you have a location specified? if so try removing this.

Comment: Thanks @TimTharratt this works, but my doubt is how it will behave if I have multiple subscription on same rg with same service principal. Also location is share by managed  image rg and custom image rg.

Comment: If the answer helps you solve the issue you can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create the image using Packer with an exist resource group as the creation, there is a limitation for it.

> Providing temp_resource_group_name or location in combination with
>   build_resource_group_name is not allowed.

So you should more carefully for the creation, and for more details about that, see [Azure Resource Manager Builder](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/azure.html).

**Update**

The update for the issue that multi subscriptions in the same resource group. The property `subscription_id` already shows that which subscription was chosen for the build_resource_group_name. So you do not worry about which subscription will be chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Charles. I'm looking for a more precise answer. Removing location works but my doubt is how it will behave if I have multiple subscription on same rg with same service principal.

Comment: You can take a look at the `subscription_id` in the file, it also explains to you.